# How do I use gnuplot from C++?

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot some graphs with (x,y) points which is generated from a C++ programme. I can successfully plot these data from gnuplot command from a terminal.

But I want to plot the same thing from a C++ programme, is this thing possible in ubuntu 16.04 lts ?

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at the [GnuPlotScripting](https://github.com/vincent-picaud/GnuPlotScripting)  C++17 lib.

Comment: @PicaudVincent, I had a look at the library and it may fit what I am trying to do.  I wonder if it can do candlestick charts, as well as embedding the plot into a window created by `wxWidgets`?

Comment: Also you may wanna contact `gnuplot` to add that library to their list of interfaces [here](http://www.gnuplot.info/links.html).

Comment: @CaTx thanks to `free_form` you have access to all gnuplot commands, by example `script.free_form("plot {} using 1:3:2:6:5 with candlesticks", data);` should work. Concerning wxWidgets nothing is present in my package to do that, sorry

Comment: @CaTx Thanks for the suggestion. I had made the request in the past, but there was no update.

Comment: That's a shame!  I am glad to find the library and look forward to testing it out.

Answer (score 13):

Sure, just install gnuplot using standard package command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnuplot
```

After that you just need to integrate gnuplot iostream header which is an interface for gnuplot from C++:

```
#include "gnuplot-iostream.h"
```

This header is not included when you install gnuplot but can be found [here](https://github.com/dstahlke/gnuplot-iostream.git). Here you have an example link of iostream for reference: [iostream example code C++](http://stahlke.org/dan/gnuplot-iostream/)

Answer (score 6):

I am adding an answer since I cannot comment.
As hackela said you can install gnuplot, then you can install gnuplot-iostream from aptitude instead of dowloading manually the header file, with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libgnuplot-iostream-dev
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option: C++ lib matplotplusplus is actually sending drawing commands to GnuPlot. It provides an API similar to python matplotlib. It is available in C++ package manager vcpkg.